# "invisible" data HTML tag

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like a PhP-based MediaWiki server to transfer data to client-side JavaScript. Some programmers use custom attributes in HTML tags to feed data, for example:

```
<input type="text" customAttribute="Some custom data"></input>
```

The problem is that the `input` element is visible on my output page (it creates an input box!).

Are there invisible HTML elements I can use to feed in information without affecting the page visually? Would it be possible to have custom HTML tags for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a very nice [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function exactly for that use case. You can attach data to elements without polluting the attributes, and you don't have to mess around with HTML.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a `type="hidden"` input.

```
<input type="hidden" customAttribute="My data"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Gpby/

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Don't forget you could also add a value to that element and use a name/id instead of a custom attribute, although if you want many attributes, you would probably be best to use the custom attributes. :)

Answer (score 2):

There aren't really any HTML tags that wouldn't be visible in source code (does that even make sense?). The closest one that's commonly used for storing data is `<input type="hidden">`. If you use HTML5, you can also use [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to store information.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP meant. I think it was that the `input` field was visibly viewable on display of the page, although the data attributes are a nice addition.

Answer (score 0):

The [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute could be used.

```
<input hidden type="text" customAttribute="Some custom data"></input>
```